# Populate Combobox on button click event

Tags: wpf

I have a basic form with a button and a combobox.  I am able to populate the combobox using this code:

```
    private void PopulateDropDown() {
      List<ArchetypeComboData> cmb = new List<ArchetypeComboData>();
      cmb.Add(new ArchetypeComboData {
        Archetype = "Item 1",
        Confidence = "Low"
      });
      cmb.Add(new ArchetypeComboData {
        Archetype = "Item 2",
        Confidence = "Neutral"
      });
      cmb.Add(new ArchetypeComboData {
        Archetype = "Item 3",
        Confidence = "High"
      });

      comboBox1.DataContext = cmb;

    }
```

by calling PopulateDrowDown() from the MainWindow() constructor, however, if I remove the call to PopulateDropDown() from the MainWindow(), and try to call it from say a Button click event, the dropdown does not get populated.  ex

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      PopulateDropDown();

//    this does not work...  
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure it's something simple and bone-headed :)

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted the question, and retried the same code, it started working.. Not sure what I changed, but please ignore this question.  It works as it should.